# org.json.JSONException: Value DB of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm making an Android login feature. Originally, it was made using localhost, but it is re-created with free hosting because it wants to have an external connection.

I uploaded php over FTP and changed url, which used to be localhost, to a free hosting url.

```
    final static private String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/login.php";
```

to

```
    final static private String URL = "http://stock123.dothome.co.kr/login.php";
```

When using a local host, it was run as an AVD, and when using a free hosting url, it was run as an Android device.

When using a local host, the login is executed without any problem, but after changing url, an error occurs below.

> org.json.JSONException: Value DB of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I don't know where the problem is. 

This is login.php

```
<?php


  $con = mysqli_connect('mirpasec.ddns.net:50106', 'extern_user', 'extern_pass', 'extern_user');

 if (!$con)
  {
     echo "MySQL 접속 에러 : ";
     echo mysqli_connect_error();
     exit();
  } else {
    echo "DB connect success";
  }

     $userID = $_POST["userID"];
     $userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];

     $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userID = ? AND userPassword = ?");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userID, $userPassword);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
     mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $userPassword, $userEmail, $userName, $userPhone);

     $response = array();
     $response["success"] = false;

     while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
      $response["success"] = true;
      $response["userID"] = $userID;
      $response["userPassword"] = $userPassword;
      $response["userEmail"] = $userEmail;
      $response["userName"] = $userName;
      $response["userPhone"] = $userPhone;
     }

     echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I don't think there is a problem with json code because it worked normally when using the local host. There seems to be a problem connecting to the DB. Is there anything else I need to add when using FTP?

Comment: The problem does not appear to have anything to do with Android or FTP. The connection from your web server to your database server is the primary suspect, since that is what has changed since when it was working before (all running on the same server). Maybe some more `echo` logging statements would help you find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Value DB of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I think the issue is you are not getting your `JSONObject` because somehow you didn't reach your backend api .

please check if you have necessary permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You need to add the following permission to grant your application to use the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```